# First using ACF - doesnt show image on page

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I installed plugin ACF for Wordpress. I created 3 fields (text, image, text area), set rules, fill on the page with text but it doesn't show anything! May I set something in PHP? I am new in this, I´m sorry. What have I done wrong?
Please tell me what can I do with text area (for example). 
Thank you very much.

Comment: It might be helpful to provide the rules that you've set.

Comment: Ok. Show this field group if Page is index

Comment: It is ok because it show me at the draft of page. BUT not on the "rendered" page. Do you understand me?

Comment: the fields you created won't display automaticly. you need to add functions to the templates i.e. the_field('my_text_field');
Read more here: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/getting-started/code-examples/